# javascript: document.scripts and getElementsByTagName("script") returning subset

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that parses the javascript on a page. When I right-click "view page source" I see many scripts, one of which I care about. In my extension, (sometimes) I cannot find that script. I can find it when the page first loads, but after I click around a bit, my extension can no longer find the script. In both cases, "view page source" shows the script that I am looking for.

Chrome extension code - this gets called when I click the extension's button:

```
// scripts = getElementsByTagName("script"); // doesn't work either
var scripts = document.scripts;
for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
   var line = scripts[i].innerHTML;
   var match = line.match('some regex expression here');
   if(match != null) {   
       ... do some stuff
   }
}
```

I want to find the script in both cases. I am wondering whether "show page source" is pulling the source javascript from outside files, whereas document.scripts is not, or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*View page source* shows you the html document as it was first downloaded from the server. After that, all kinds of DOM manipulation are posible that may add or remove tags from the page. If you use the *Inspect element* right click option, you'll be able to see the current status of the document, and check if the `script` tag you are looking for is still there.